# Animating an element differently to slide in/out of view on scroll up / down

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a new portfolio for myself, using Bootstrap framework and I want to animate my slider based on the direction that the user is scrolling.

For example I already have an animation to slide the navbar class in. But as the user scrolls down the page I want to hide the navbar this is to give the user more visibility on the screen when browsing content. Then when they attempt to scroll back up the page I want to slide the .navbar class back in again.

Now I can easily get this to work if I target a specific element or pixel height, but that doesn't help me. I know it's achievable as I've seen it on several websites (LinkedIn for example).

So I'm wondering if it's a case of targeting positive or negative values on the y axis or something?

Comment: just add/remove the animation class together with the code you're using for fixer header.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you mean, can you elaborate please? Getting the animation to fire is easy. Like you said it's just a simple add/remove class. That doesn't help me to call the function based on the direction the user is scrolling on the y axis.

I don't want the animation to be triggered on a specific element or scroll point but on the direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    var lastScrollPosition = 0;
window.onscroll = function() {
    var newScrollPosition = window.scrollY;

    if (newScrollPosition < lastScrollPosition){
        //upward - code here
    }else{
        //downward - code here
    }
    lastScrollPosition = newScrollPosition;
}
```